# How to plot imshow starting at a certain radius?

Tags: python, imshow

I am trying to make a plot to specify gravitational redshift as a function of distance. However, i have a problem in plotting. I want to plot it from `rs=1.0` because no object can be detectable within a schwarzshild radius, `rs=1.0` in my case.

[image]

I tried to do mask but it was not working. Is there any method to do contour plot with the starting radius about at `r>1`?. Actually, in the above figure, I want to let my imshow to plot the amount of redshift from the blue solid circle, not at `r=0` (i have no idea why it starts there).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rs=1
ang=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,2000)
x, y = np.mgrid[2:100, 2:100]
dist = np.hypot(x, y) # Linear distance from point 0, 0
z = np.sqrt(1/dist)
f=1/np.sqrt((1-rs*z)/(1-rs/4))*(1/10)

plt.imshow(f, interpolation='bilinear')

a=np.cos(ang)
b=np.sin(ang)

plt.xlim(0,15)
plt.ylim(0,15)
plt.plot(a,b)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misunderstanding in the kind of plot. `plt.imshow` creates colormappings of 2D-arrays - but the scales of the axes are not showing the independant data variables, but only the indices of the array. This is different from e.g. `plt.contourf`.

In fact, your array `f`  doesn't even have values at `[x=1, y=1]`, as `x`and `y` start at 2...

Let's compare `imshow` and `contourf`:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)
axs[0].imshow(f, interpolation='bilinear')
axs[0].set_xlim(0,15)
axs[0].set_ylim(0,15)

axs[1].contourf(x, y, f)
axs[1].set_aspect(1)

axs[1].set_xlim(0,15)
axs[1].set_ylim(0,15)
```

[image]

Or in other words: check the limits of your scales without setting xlim and ylim: they go from -0,5 to 97,5 instead of 2 to 99...

However, there are interesting kwargs of `imshow` for you.
Look what happens to the above plot with

```
axs[0].imshow(f, interpolation='bilinear', origin='lower', extent=[2, 99, 2, 99])
```

[image]

Comment: oh if it is possible, would you please let me know how to depict hollow contour plot??

Comment: What do you mean by _"hollow contour plot"_? Your circle with radius r=1 as a white hole? But this circle is _not_ within the bounds of your data, because x and y start at 2.